# PowerShell ValidateLength with Read-Host

Tags: powershell

I am trying to use ValidateLength declaration with Read-Host, however I cannot get it to work. If I use it without Read-Host it works flawless. Here are some basic examples:

[ValidateLength(1,3)]$test = '123'

[ValidateLength(1,3)]$test1 = Read-Host
123
Attribute cannot be added because it would cause the variable test1 with value
123 to become invalid.
At line:1 char:1
+ [ValidateLength(1,3)]$test1 = Read-Host
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : MetadataError: (:) [], ValidationMetadataExcepti
   on
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ValidateSetFailure

Is it possible to use ValidateLength declaration with Read-Host?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare your Read-Host as a string (since ValidateLength can not accept anything except a string) and the problem is solved.

```
[ValidateLength(1,3)]$test1 = [String](Read-Host "Input")
```

I am not sure why you have to cast a type on it, but it solves the problem.

Comment: @CB. 8 is valid. It's not the number, but the length of the string that is validated. So 999 is valid because it's 3 characters long, but 6234 is not because it is 4 characters long. This isn't number specific, ABC is valid, while ABCD is not.

Comment: You can also place the type at the beginning as well: `[string][ValidateLength(1,3)]$test1 = (Read-Host "Input")`. Still weird that it doesn't allow any other type besides a string.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician :) yes :)

Comment: @TheMadTechnician Thanks that is exactly what I needed. Very odd you have to cast the type but thanks for the help.