# ValidateLength Powershell

Tags: powershell

This is my first script so don't beat me up to bad!

I'm working on a script that creates a network directory & AD group based on user input. The following is what I've gotten so far. It works but I would like to make a few enhancements.

I would like to Validate length for user inputs. I was able to find an article ([PowerShell ValidateLength with Read-Host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24537202/powershell-validatelength-with-read-host)) that explains how to use the ValidateLength string to check a user's input. This works great, however, I would like to include it in a loop. Example if user does not input exactly X characters - then retry. Right now it just errors out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
[ValidateLength(2,2)]$Division = [string](Read-Host -Prompt 'Please enter the TWO digit division number ')
[ValidateLength(4,4)]$Matter = [string](Read-Host -Prompt 'Please enter the FOUR digit matter number ')
[ValidateLength(4,4)]$Client = [string](Read-Host -Prompt 'Please enter the FOUR digit client number ')
```

Comment: If you want the user to input numbers, why are you validating the length of values cast to string instead of [validating the range](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847743.aspx) of values cast to int?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although the various `[Validate`... attributes work on variables, it's a non-standard usage (and few people know about them). It works best when you *do* want to error out.

If you don't, just check it yourself and decide and what to do in the event that it's not what you want:

```
do {
    $Division = [string](Read-Host -Prompt 'Please enter the TWO digit division number ')
    if ($Divison.Length -ne 2) {
        continue
    }

    $Matter = [string](Read-Host -Prompt 'Please enter the FOUR digit matter number ')
    if ($Matter.Length -ne 4) {
        continue
    }

    $Client = [string](Read-Host -Prompt 'Please enter the FOUR digit client number ')
    if ($Client.Length -ne 4) {
        continue
    }

    break
} while ($true)
```

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers it's an example for a single prompt, but he has 3 to prompt for, so actually I updated it, but there's still cleaner ways. Post another answer ;)

Comment: Thanks! This worked great. I am starting to pick-up on how to write stronger do/whiles.

Comment: @JaredZ that's great! Glad it was helpful, but I strongly recommend you use (and accept) Ansgar's answer. It's more complete, more correct, and it's the way I would do it if I weren't writing a quick answer on SO between meetings :)

Answer (score 3):

As [@briantist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39854705/1630171) already pointed out, validation functions were made for a different purpose (parameter validation). You have a different scenario, since you want to keep prompting the user until a valid value is entered. Validation functions just don't work well in this scenario for a number of reasons:

- they throw an error instead of returning a boolean value, which is fine for a function call, but not for validating a value.
- they don't repeat, so you need additional code anyway,
- their parameters can't be variables.

I would probably put the input/validation loop in a function and use numeric comparisons instead of checking the length of a string, since you're asking the user to input numbers anyway.

```
function Get-Number {
  [CmdletBinding()]
  Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$Prompt,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [int]$Min = 0,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [int]$Max = 9999
  )

  # prevent infinite loop due to impossible condition
  if ($Min -gt $Max) { throw 'Min cannot be greater than max.' }

  $ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'
  do {
    $num = Read-Host -Prompt $Prompt
    $valid = $Min -le $num -and $Max -ge $num
    if (-not $valid) { Write-Host "Invalid value: $num" }
  } until ($valid)

  return [int]$num
}

$Division = Get-Number -Prompt 'Please enter the TWO digit division number' -Min 10 -Max 99
$Matter   = Get-Number -Prompt 'Please enter the FOUR digit matter number' -Min 1000 -Max 9999
$Client   = Get-Number -Prompt 'Please enter the FOUR digit client number' -Min 1000 -Max 9999
```

Comment: This is definitely a better approach. For checking validity, I also like to use ranges: `$valid = $Min..$Max -contains $num` or `$valid = $num -in $Min..$Max`

Comment: Thanks! This helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You could utilize a while loop:

```
$Division = $null
while ($null -eq $Division) {
    [ValidateLength(2,2)]$Division = [string](Read-Host -Prompt 'Please enter the TWO digit division number ')
}
```